# How to sort the value in an output CSV file with XSLT using one of the columns

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an XML that I am trying to transform using XSLT. I want the output CSV file to be sorted using the TRANNUM Column in ascending order. See a snippet from the XSLT file I want to modify below. The TRANNUM column has 3 possible values which are 10,11 and 12. I want the rows where the TRANNUM value equals 10 to come first followed by 11 and then 12 in the CSV output file. Below XSLT is working but not sorting the values using the TRANNUM values in ascending order but using the values of  tns:Company/tns:Code ('RETGP', 'RTLPM', 'RETRT') to sort the output instead of 10, 11, 12

**Below is the extract from my XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org"
    xmlns:wd="http://"
    xmlns:tns="http://"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math wd tns xtt" version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="p.source"></xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="tns:OutboundFile">
        <header1>FinJournals&#xD;&#xA;TRANNUM,DATE,PROPERTY,ACCOUNT,POSTMONTH,BOOKNUM,AMOUNT,REMARK,REF,DESC,SEGMENT2,DISPLAYTYPE,ReverseNextMonth</header1>
        <JournalEntry>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tns:Journal_Entry/tns:Journal_Line[tns:Ledger_Account != '888888']"
                group-by="string-join((tns:Company/tns:Code,tns:Ledger_Account,description),'+')">
            <xsl:sort select="tns:Company/tns:Code" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="format-number(sum(current-group()/tns:Ledger_Debit_Amount) - sum(current-group()/tns:Ledger_Credit_Amount),'#0.00') != '0.00'">
                    <JournalLine>
                        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        <TRANNUM>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETGP'">10</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RTLPM'">11</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETRT'">12</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </TRANNUM><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        <DATE><xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/></DATE><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        <PROPERTY>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETGP'">22000</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RTLPM'">26000</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETRT'">23000</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </PROPERTY><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
```

**Sample Current Output**

TRANNUM,DATE,PROPERTY,ACCOUNT,POSTMONTH

10,01/11/2023,22000,720010,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,720025,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,211070,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,720005,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,211070,01/13/2023,1

12,01/11/2023,23000,720025,01/13/2023,1

12,01/11/2023,23000,211070,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211070,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211010,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211065,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211010,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211070,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211015,01/13/2023,1

**Sample Expected Output**

TRANNUM,DATE,PROPERTY,ACCOUNT,POSTMONTH

10,01/11/2023,22000,211070,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,720025,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,211070,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,720010,01/13/2023,1

10,01/11/2023,22000,720025,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211070,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211010,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211065,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211010,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211015,01/13/2023,1

11,01/11/2023,26000,211070,01/13/2023,1

12,01/11/2023,23000,720005,01/13/2023,1

12,01/11/2023,23000,211070,01/13/2023,1

Comment: Just loop 3 times or use xsl:sort

Comment: Why the tag for XSLT 1.0 if the code uses `version="3.0"` and `for-each-group` which is 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the input XML used in your example - see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org"
    xmlns:wd="http://"
    xmlns:tns="http://"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math wd tns xtt" version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="p.source"></xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="tns:OutboundFile">

    <xsl:param name="code-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:integer)"
      select="map { 'RETGP' : 10, 'RTLPM' : 11, 'RETRT' : 12 }"/>
        <header1>FinJournals&#xD;&#xA;TRANNUM,DATE,PROPERTY,ACCOUNT,POSTMONTH,BOOKNUM,AMOUNT,REMARK,REF,DESC,SEGMENT2,DISPLAYTYPE,ReverseNextMonth</header1>
        <JournalEntry>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tns:Journal_Entry/tns:Journal_Line[tns:Ledger_Account != '888888']"
                group-by="string-join((tns:Company/tns:Code,tns:Ledger_Account,description),'+')">
                <xsl:sort select="$code-map(tns:Company/tns:Code)"/>
                <xsl:if test="format-number(sum(current-group()/tns:Ledger_Debit_Amount) - sum(current-group()/tns:Ledger_Credit_Amount),'#0.00') != '0.00'">
                    <JournalLine>
                        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        <TRANNUM>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETGP'">10</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RTLPM'">11</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="tns:Company/tns:Code = 'RETRT'">12</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </TRANNUM>
```

Untested as no input sample was provided.

Comment: Thank you but no changes were noticed after the transformation. I didn't share XML because it contains sensitive data.

Comment: @KayodeOlanrewajuMosaku, then consider to make the effort to provide a sample with the same structure but some dummy data that is not sensitive.

Comment: @KayodeOlanrewajuMosaku, and somehow your edit with `<xsl:sort select="tns:Company/tns:Code" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>` doesn't do what I suggested as that is to e.g. a parameter mapping the values to integer numbers and then sort on the result of using the map's integer value e.g. `<xsl:param name="code-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:integer)" select="map { 'RETGP' : 10, 'RTLPM' : 11, 'RETRT' : 12 }"/>` and then `<xsl:for-each-group ...><xsl:sort select="$code-map(tns:Company/tns:Code)"/>...`.

Comment: Thank you. Your code actually worked and already solved the problem. I did not see the sort part I only added this "select="map { 'RETGP' : 10, 'RTLPM' : 11, 'RETRT' : 12 }"/>" from your code so i didn't see any change when i run the transformation. I just take another look and saw your explanation on the sort.